# Can I install a python module locally and import in my program instead of installing global

Tags: python-2.7, module

With node.js, I can typically do something like `npm install example` and then my code can import and use that module like `var m = require('example'); m.dostuff();`. The module and any dependencies are saved locally in a directory and that code and my code is portable.

Some modules run as command line programs when you install like `npm install -g example` and run from the command line `./example dostuff`. These modules get installed globally and are part of the PATH.

I am trying to install [mkdocs](http://www.mkdocs.org) locally. However running `pip install mkdocs` seems to install it globally which is not desirable.

Is it possible to install locally like my first example and invoke from another python program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
pip install --target=/target/dir/name mkdocs
```

But you need to add /target/dir/name to PYTHONPATH env variable.

Comment: That appeared to work as far as installing but how do I import and invoke `mkdocs` from another python file?

Comment: You have to add /target/dir/name to PYTHONPATH env variable to let python know what other place to look for when python is looking for the mkdocs module. After that you can just `import mkdocs` in your python program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtualenv to avoid system wide installation. It'll create dedicated virtual environment to run your python programs in.

```
# install virtualenv
$ [sudo] pip install virtualenv
# create virtual environment 'docs_env'
$ virtualenv docs_env
# activate virtual environment (it adds docs_env/bin as first PATH entry)
$ source ./docs_env/bin/activate
# install mkdocs in virtual environment
(docs_env)$ pip install mkdocs
# you can run python scripts anywhere, as long as 'docs_env' is activated
(docs_env)$ python do_something_with_mkdocs.py
# if you need to leave 'docs_env' (it undoes PATH change)
(docs_env)$ deactivate
```

More infos: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html